# Mongoose relations add multiple Id to a Schema (many to One)

Tags: mongoose

So I want to reference many vehciles to my client schema, but I don't know how to do it.

Here is my schema:

```
const { Schema, model, Types } = require('mongoose');
const ClientSchema = new Schema(
  {
    id: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
    },
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client First Name is required.'],
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client Last Name is required.'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client Email Address is required.'],
      unique: true,
    },
    company: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    },
    phone: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client Phone Number is required.'],
      unique: true,
    },
    country: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client Country Location is required.'],
      default: 'Switzerland',
    },
    street: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client Street is required.'],
    },
    city: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Client City Location is required.'],
    },
    zip: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Client's Country Zipcode is required."],
    },
    vehicles: [
      {
        type: Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'vehicle',
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

module.exports = model('Client', ClientSchema);
```

And here is my route:

```
router.post('/create', passVerify, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const random = nanoid(5);
    const id = random.toUpperCase();
    if (req.body.vehicles)
      var vehicles = toId('6200d870c6d4758d29a86bed, 620b45cacddc8898b8919f3d');
    const body = new Client({ ...req.body, id, vehicles });
    const client = await body.save();

    if (client)
      res.status(200).send({
        success: true,
        data: client,
      });
    else
      res.status(404).send({
        success: false,
        message: 'Something went wrong adding the client.',
      });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      message: error,
    });
  }
});
```

So I want to asign many vehciles to a user, but don't know the way around to it. I think the schema now can accept more than one vehcile beacuse it has the array, but to add I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You can push multiple data to an array by using $push with $each.
For example:

```
 Client.updateOne(
     { id: clientID },
     {$push: {vehicles: {$each: [value1, value2, value3, ...]},
     function(error, success){}
  )
```

(Check documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: thank you, but In this case I'm not doing an update, can you simiulate for something related to my case

Comment: when I try to add the $put and $push together it doesn't work

Comment: can you share the error message you're getting? are you creating a new client object or inserting new elements to an existing object?